# server NodeJS v6.8.1 can't connect with mssql npm package

Tags: node.js

Like my title I can't connect and make request with mssql npm package.
I arrive in post request "/getData", the first log with jsonData is display and "TEST" too but no error message or "TEST 2".

Node version: 6.8.1

This is my code :

**part of index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql');

router.post('/getData', function(req, res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

  var jsonData = req.body;
  console.log("jsonData in /getData post: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  var sqlQuery;
  switch (jsonData.myAction) {
    case "getSomething":
      sqlQuery = "SELECT S.ID FROM Something AS S WHERE S.IDUser = '" + jsonData.IDUser + "'";
      break;
    case "...":
      sqlQuery = "...";
      break;
    default:
      sqlQuery = "";
      break;
  }
  console.log("TEST");
  var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    port: '8082',
    database: 'DatabaseName'
  };

  var conn = new sql.Connection(config, function(errConn) {
    if (errConn) {
      console.log(errConn);
    }
    console.log("TEST 2");
    var request = new sql.Request(conn);
    request.query(sqlQuery, function(errReq, recordset) {
      if (errReq) {
        console.log(errReq);
      }
      console.log("Requete: " + sqlQuery);
      console.log("Resultat: " + JSON.stringify(recordset));
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
      res.end();
      connection.close();
    });
  });
});
```

If someone know why mssql can't connect please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the `mssql` connectivity process? It seems to different  https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql

Answer (score 0):

[abdulbarik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3260137/abdulbarik) has right, syntax I used was in the same page but for older version. With the new syntax it's good. Thanks